# How to associate IDs from existing nested model to new created parent model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've relationship: one `Post` with many `Pictures`. `Pictures` have been created earlier via AJAX and their IDs are stored in hidden field on one post view page. After submitting the form, `post_controller` saves only own data and skip `picture_ids` from nested model. How to associate it?

```
def create
  p_attr = params[:post]
  p_attr[:picture_ids] = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params[:post][:picture_ids])

  puts p_attr
  @post = Post.new(p_attr)

  puts @post.to_json
  @post.save
end
```

Received post:

```
{"title"=>"test", "description"=>"test", "picture_ids"=>["505eec681e7bf2b8150001a5","505eea991e7bf2b8150001a1","505ee7761e7bf2b81500018d"]}
```

Created post:

```
{"_id":"505eeed01e7bf2b8150001b1","created_at":null,"description":"test","title":"test","updated_at":null}
```

Comment: whats the output at p_attr you are printing in 3rd line of action..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly you want to take the Picture records that have already been uploaded and associate them with the Post that has just been saved.  Assuming `params[:picture_ids]` is an array after you decode the JSON you should be able to do an update all on Picture to achieve this.  Try this right after you save the post:

```
Picture.update_all(
  { :post_id => @post.id },
  :conditions => { :id => params[:picture_ids] }
)
```

Comment: I'm doing a loop on each picture ID separately and Your solution works. Thanks a lot :)